# Как установить 2 бесплатных сертификата на сервер

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, vds

Устанавливаю на сервер бесплатный сертификат командой:

***sudo certbot certonly --standalone --agree-tos --preferred-challenges http -d DOMEN1.com***

Потом:

***sudo certbot --apache --agree-tos --preferred-challenges http -d DOMEN1.com***

Сертификат успешно устанавливается, все работает. Но при попытке установить еще один сертификат для второго домена теми же командами:

***sudo certbot certonly --standalone --agree-tos --preferred-challenges http -d DOMEN2.com***

Потом:

***sudo certbot --apache --agree-tos --preferred-challenges http -d DOMEN2.com***

Сертификат устанавливается на DOMEN2.com, но на DOMEN1.com сертификат перестает работать....

Устанавливал по [этому](https://serverspace.ru/support/help/lets-encrypt-ubuntu-20-04/) мануалу

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Во-первых, если у вас сервер Apache, то standalone сертификат вам не нужен. Достаточно только команд `certbot --apache ...`. Во-вторых, отредактируйте вопрос и приложите конфигурационные файлы для DOMEN1.com и DOMEN2.com